# Positive lookahead using token types in lexer rules

Tags: java, antlr4, grammar

I am migrating a grammar that I initially wrote using [GrammarKit](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit) (GrammarKit uses Flex as its lexer).

I am struggling finding the best way to write a positive lookahead using token types in lexer rules.

Below my first experiment with a (very) simplified version of my problem using lookahead based on characters in the stream:

```
grammar PossitiveLookAheadCharacters;

@header {
    package lookahead;
}

@lexer::members {
    private boolean isChar(int charPosition, char testChar) {
        return _input.LA(charPosition) == testChar;
    }
}

r : CONS | DOT | LEFT_PAR | RIGHT_PAR;

LEFT_PAR : '(';
RIGHT_PAR : ')';
CONS : DOT {isChar(1, '(')}? {isChar(2, ')')}?;
DOT : '.';
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

This works ok because the lookahead is just based on character comparison.
If I test this using the test rig, I obtain the following expected output:

```
> grun lookahead.PossitiveLookAheadCharacters r -tokens
.()
[@0,0:0='.',<CONS>,1:0]
[@1,1:1='(',<'('>,1:1]
[@2,2:2=')',<')'>,1:2]
[@3,4:3='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

But I cannot make this work correctly if I want to write the look ahead based on token types and not in characters from the stream (as I can easily do in Flex). After some trial and error this is the closest I have arrived:

```
grammar PossitiveLookAheadTokenType;


@header {
    package lookahead;
}

@lexer::members {
    private boolean isToken(int tokenPosition, int tokenId) {
        int tokenAtPosition = new UnbufferedTokenStream(this).LA(tokenPosition);
        System.out.println("LA(" + tokenPosition + ") = " + tokenAtPosition);
        return tokenAtPosition == tokenId;
    }
}

r : CONS | DOT | LEFT_PAR | RIGHT_PAR;

LEFT_PAR : '(';
RIGHT_PAR : ')';
CONS : DOT {isToken(1, LEFT_PAR)}? {isToken(2, RIGHT_PAR)}?;
DOT : '.';
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

If I test this using the test rig, I see that the tests expressions are evaluated correctly (in short, this predicate is true: `LA(1) == LEFT_PAR && LA(2) == RIGHT_PAR`). But the first recognized token is not `[@0,0:0='.',<CONS>,1:0]` as expected, but `[@0,2:2=')',<')'>,1:2]` instead. Below the full output of my test:

```
? grun lookahead.PossitiveLookAheadTokenType r -tokens
.()
LA(1) = 1
LA(2) = 2
[@0,2:2=')',<')'>,1:2]
[@1,1:1='(',<'('>,1:1]
[@2,2:2=')',<')'>,1:2]
[@3,4:3='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

I thought that the problem may be that the input stream is not in the right position anymore, so I tried resetting its position, as illustrates this new version of the `isToken` method:

```
    private boolean isToken(int tokenPosition, int tokenId) {
        int streamPosition = _input.index();
        int tokenAtPosition = new UnbufferedTokenStream(this).LA(tokenPosition);
        _input.seek(streamPosition);
        return tokenAtPosition == tokenId;
    }
```

But this did not help.

So my ANTLR4 question is: What is the recommended way to write a positive lookahead in lexer rules using token types and not plain characters ?

In Flex this is fully possible and it is as simple as writing something like:

```
{MY_MATCH}/{TOKEN_TO_THE_RIGHT}
```

What I love about the Flex approach here is that it is fully declarative and based on token types, not chars. I am wondering if something similar is possible in ANTLR4.

Comment: You are migrating a lexer. You can't write a grammar in *flex(1).*

Comment: Hi @user207421, what I am migrating is a Grammar written initially for an IntelliJ plugin. GrammarKit (the IntelliJ library for writing grammars) uses Flex as its lexer. The parser is not in Flex of course. I have just clarified this in my question.

Comment: I would consider tackling this in the parser grammar, rather than lexar grammar.   It seems like the parser would be better suited to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work the way you imagine it because what you are trying to do is to use a token (which is the result of a lexer rule) in an ongoing lexer rule. That means the lexer is in the process of determining the current token and therefore cannot determine another token at the same time.

What you probably want is a parser rule. In this scenario the lexer has done all the work already and you can easily look around for other tokens.

```
cons: DOT {isToken(1, LEFT_PAR) && isToken(2, RIGHT_PAR)}?;
r : cons | DOT | LEFT_PAR | RIGHT_PAR;
```

```
@parser::members {
    private boolean isToken(int position, int tokenType) {
        return _input.LT(position).getType() == tokenType;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mike. I was aware of the alternative you proposed.
It is a pity if this is truly the best I can do with ANTLR4 since (1) I want to define the token type reported by the lexer based on lookahead conditions; (2) this is trivial to do declaratively with Flex.
I had the hope there is a way to properly reset the lexer to the state it had before the type lookahead I wrote by means of instantiating UnbufferedTokenStream. I did have the feeling that this is not the right way to do it.
But I am very surprised that this kind of lookahead just cannot be done at the lexer level.

Comment: True, that's not possible. You cannot lookhead a token that has not been produced. But so far it seems it's not a feature that many people ask for.